# Listing files without unzipping and selective unzip

Tags: 7zip

We have several big sized zip files. Each of these zips contains excel file and a bunch of bmp images.

I was just wondering if 7-zip allows listing the content of the zip without unzipping it? And also if we can selectively unzip the excel file?

Currently, I use c# console program utilizing diagnostic process to execute 7z.exe. It would be nice not to unzip the entire thing.

Comment: SO is not good place to ask for instructions on how to use software (like 7zip) even if you launch it from C# code.

Comment: http://www.dotnetperls.com/7-zip-examples
or
http://superuser.com/questions/321829/extract-a-certain-file-from-an-archive-with-7-zip-from-the-command-line
should help.

Comment: SO or not SO but this was really good to find this question in a web search because I immediately understood what I should do to solve my (a little bit different) question. But if this can be moved to Superuser, maybe that's more correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For listing you can use the [list command (l) to the 7zip.exe](http://7zip.bugaco.com/7zip/MANUAL/commands/list.htm)

```
7z l archive.zip
```

For selectively extracting files you can use different commands to the [extract command](http://7zip.bugaco.com/7zip/MANUAL/commands/extract.htm). Something like:

```
7z e archive.zip -oc:\soft *.xls
```